# DNS.EXE allocates 5000+ ports immediately

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

This command clears all open UDP ports by DNS.EXE

```
net stop dns
```

After restarting the DNS service, DNS.EXE allocates 5000+ ports.

```
net start dns
```

It doesn't consume extensive memory or cpu. However I noticed/alarmed many http/smtp/pop3 connection problems to the server because of timeouts. I just examined and found tons of open ports by DNS.EXE. Currports displays UDP local ports from 50000 to 56000, local addresses are :: and remote addresses are empty. Last lines of netstat - a command are below:

```
UDP    [::]:55976             *:*   
UDP    [::]:55977             *:*   
UDP    [::]:55978             *:*     
UDP    [::]:55979             *:*     
UDP    [::]:55980             *:*     
UDP    [::]:55981             *:*     
UDP    [::]:55982             *:*
```

I didn't notice these ports before, so I don't know for sure it is ok or not. What do you think? I did restart the server and monitoring/alert mails are NOT continuing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a [well-known](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sbs/some-services-may-fail-to-start-or-may-not-work-properly-after-installing-ms08-037-951746-and-951748) [side](https://blogs.msmvps.com/alunj/2008/07/19/dns-server-reserves-2500-ports/) [effect](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956188) of the hotfix distributed to address [MS08-037](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms08-037), since the hotfix is intended to decrease the predictability of ports used for DNS responses.

You can restrict the amount of ports used by defining a lower Socket Pool Size, as described in [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649174(v=ws.10).aspx):

### Using [dnscmd.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069.aspx)

- Open an elevated Command Prompt (Run as Administrator...)
- Issue `dnscmd /Config /SocketPoolSize <value>` where `<value>` is a number between 0 and 10000

### Using regedit.exe

- Open `regedit.exe` and expand the `HKLM` hive
- Navigate to `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\DNS\Parameters`
- If not already present, create a new `DWORD` value named `SocketPoolSize`
- Set a decimal value between 0 and 10000
- Restart the DNS Server service: `net stop dns && net start dns`

Be aware that setting the value too low, effectively defeats the purpose of MS08-037

If you're on Windows Server 2008 R2 and just want to make sure that a number of individual UDP endpoints are not used by DNS, you can also specify a list of port ranges to be excluded from use by DNS:

```
dnscmd /Config /SocketPoolExcludedPortRanges <start>-<end>
```

Comment: The command to exclude specific ports is: `dnscmd /config /SocketPoolExcludedPortRanges [start]-[end]`, replacing [start] and [end] with your desired port range. You can also edit the registry value  '`SocketPoolExcludedPortRanges`' manually (located in the same registry key as mentioned above).